# runaway argument with fraction

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to write the following equation:

```
\begin{equation}
    \text{$N_R$} \text{x} (\text{$\Delta\sigma_R$})^m = 2 \text{x} {10^6} \text{x} (\text{$\Delta\sigma_C$})^m    with  m = 3 for \text{N} \leq 5 \text{x} {10^6}
    \text{$N_R$} \text{x} (\text{$\Delta\tau_R$})^m = 2 \text{x} {10^6} \text{x} (\text{$\Delta\tau_C$})^m    with  m = 5 for \text{N} \leq 5 \text{x} {10^6}
    where \text{$\Delta\sigma_D$} = \text{$\frac{2}{5}^{\frac{1}{3}$} \text{x} \text{$\Delta\sigma_C$} = 0.7368 \text{x} \text{$\Delta\sigma_C$} is the constant amplitude fatigue limit
    \end{equation}
```

But getting error as:

```
Runaway argument?
{$\frac{2}{5}^{\frac{1}{3}$} \text{x} \text{$\Delta\sigma_C$} =\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \text@ was complete.
<to be read again>
             \par
```

May please help....

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why do you use `$` inside a math mode environment? This is not necessary.

Comment: Welcome, it seems that this is meant for different lines. You cannot do that with `equation`.  Also, i think all your uses of `\text`  and inline math are wrong.

Comment: To give a direct answer, the problem lies in the third line, replace `\text{$\frac{2}{5}^{\frac{1}{3}$}` by `\text{$\frac{2}{5}^{\frac{1}{3}}$}`. Note the double braces before the second `$`. *Not* that I would recommend typesetting your equation this way.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for the following, but i am really not sure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    N_R \times (\Delta\sigma_R)^m &= 2 \times {10^6} \times (\Delta\sigma_C)^m    
&&\text{with~}  m = 3 \text{~for~} N\leq 5 \times {10^6}\\
N_R \times (\Delta\tau_R)^m &= 2 \times {10^6} \times (\Delta\tau_C)^m    
&&\text{with~}  m = 5 \text{~for~} N \leq 5 \times {10^6}
\end{align}
where $\Delta\sigma_D = \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \times \Delta\sigma_C = 0.7368 \times \Delta\sigma_C $
is the constant amplitude fatigue limit
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir! But my problem is not in 1st two equations but after "where \text.....

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Dear @Sitesh, your code is full of problems. I recommend to read an introduction to LaTeX before doing any more work. It will be a good investment.

Comment: You can copy paste my example and directly compile it. You will be able to see the output directly.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what you really want to get, but this might be another solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 N_R \times (\Delta\sigma_R)^m = \num{2e6}\times(\Delta\sigma_C)^m
\end{equation}

with $m = 3 \quad\forall\quad N\leq\num{5e6}$

\begin{equation}
 N_R \times (\Delta\tau_R)^m = \num{2e6}\times(\Delta\tau_C)^m
\end{equation}

with $m = 5 \quad\forall\quad N\leq\num{5e6}$

where

\begin{equation}
 \Delta\sigma_D = \Bigl(\frac{2}{5}\Bigr)^{\frac{1}{3}} \times
 \Delta\sigma_C = 0.7368 \times \Delta\sigma_C
\end{equation}

is the constant amplitude fatigue limit

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should be aware that every blank line results in a new paragraph and disrupts the sentence (and the spacing).

Comment: You're right, of course. But this is intended (and as we do not exactly know, what the OP really wants to achieve, this is only a guess).

Comment: Thank you soooo much Jurgen Sir!! Hats off to you!! The solution suggested by you is exactly the one I wanted to write.....Really grateful to you...